# Chrome dev tools - How to merge "styles" and "computed" tabs together?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm getting 2 different tabs for "styles" and "computed" in dev tools. Earlier they were in a single tab and I'm more comfortable with that view.

How can I get that layout back?

I have tried re-sizing the width of dev tools section, it didn't work.

[image: Desired Layout]

[image: Current Layout]

Comment: This is the new intended behavior in devtools, see https://crbug.com/1073899. They will add a switch to show both panels in the future. So, you will suffer until then or use a separate older portable Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm Any workaround for this?

Comment: No, your only choices are to suffer or to use an older portable Chrome.

Comment: dukh... i also experiencing this. found this article. at least i know now that this is intended and will be fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @wOxxOm.

Looks like this is the new intended behaviour in devtools.

[What's New In DevTools (Chrome 85)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/06/devtools#computed-pane)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the developers are coming up with a solution after the community spoke up:

[View the issue thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1073899#c26)

Comment: It looks like the Computed Panel has been put back in [Chrome 86 DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/06/devtools#computed-pane)

Answer (score 1):

You can't anymore as of **July 2020**, since it seems like an intended new behavior as of the [Chrome 85 Update](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/06/devtools#computed-pane).

An alternative solution that has a similar display is the **[Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) Web Developer Tools**.

It looks similar to how **Chrome Developer Tools** used to look.

**Firefox Developer Edition - Web Developer Tools**:
[image]